# How come this redirect does not work with this section of code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
foreach (string oName in oValues)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form[oName]))
    {
        oCount += 1;
    }
}
if (oCount == 0)
{
    _clientID = Request.Form["ClientID"];
    _password = Request.Form["Password"];
    _pracType = Request.Form["PracType"];
    _encrypt = Request.Form["Encrypt"];

    if (GetCRC(_clientID) == _password)
    {
        if (_clientID != null)
        {
            var verify = VerifyClientInformation(int.Parse(_clientID));
            var gsa = new GSDataLayer.Authentication.Auth();

            gsa.CreateAuthEntry(_clientID, _password, _pracType, _encrypt, verify.CanUpdate);
            _aMgr.GotoHomePage();
        }
        else
        {
            error.Text = "This conditional failed.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _aMgr.GotoErrorPage("nocrc"); 
    }

}
else
{
    _aMgr.GotoErrorPage("noform");  
}
```

the `GotoErrorPage` method:

```
public void GotoErrorPage(string errorcode)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress != "127.0.0.1") // for testing only
    {
        var instance = new Control();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(instance.ResolveClientUrl(
                     string.Format("~/ErrorPage.aspx?e={0}", errorcode)));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

If `oCount` is 0, it redirects just fine but if it is > 0 the redirect does not happen. Any ideas on why this might be?

thanks

## edit

Well, I feel rather silly...the conditional for the `UserHostAddress` in `GotoErrorPage()` was the culprit. I had forgotten that this was remnant from my initial testing because I did not want any redirects to happen, just outputting text (errors, results, etc). After removing that conditional, redirects happen just fine.

What is throwing me for a spin, though, is it was working fine earlier. Although, I think I also figured that out as well. Since I am developing this on a network, some of my colleagues can access it via the intranet by using my computer's name (`program003`) instead of `localhost`. I think before the 'problem' showed up, I was using my computer's name instead of `localhost` while testing. Regardless, when I use `localhost`, the IP is `127.0.0.1`, but when I use `program003` I get this IPv6 address:

> `fe80::b1d7:b18b:d10f:f526%8`

If I am not mistaken, the loopback address for IPv6 is supposed to be `::1`? Very strange.

Comment: When oCount == 0, does it redirect to the homepage?  If so, that's being called by the "GotoHomePage()" not the GotoErrorPage() method.

Comment: Well before it redirects it reads in the form information, and does a secondary validation on the data. Then if everything checks out it will redirect to the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my edit for problem/solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the logic if `GetCRC(_clientID) == _password` is true and `_clientID != null` is false, then you're left with no action taken at all, so you have at least one possible explanation there.

May I also take the opportunity to say how much the dropped braces and hungarian breaks my mind? This is very hard to read for my eyes.

Comment: sorry, for some reason i like how the code looks w/o braces. i will update the code to have all braces. I will investigate if that conditional you pointed out is indeed the culprit.

Comment: I would give a junior colleague who wrote that a very hard time, but it's all a matter of opinion :) fwiw, you said in your explanation that the ocount=0 path works whereas I'm describing a failure path for that. It's just one problem, not necessarily *the* problem.

Comment: Well, that is not the offending code path. hmm this was working earlier I think, and then I did shuffle some code around. Well actually I replaced an if/then statement with the foreach loop you see now, but that doesn't seem like it would break the functionality. Correct me if I am wrong on this, it would not surprise me :)

Answer (score 0):

Where is "errorcode" defined in your GotoErrorPage() method?  Does it accept a parameter?

Comment: your request has been obliged.